# Populate a Combo Box with an enum class in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, enums

I have been looking around for a solution to my problem, but I haven't been able to find one that applies directly to my situation. Essentially, I have a few separate enum classes, and I would like to store their string values in a combo box for the user to choose from, however simply using `ComboBox.getItems().setAll(Enum.values());` doesn't populate the list.

My code is as follows, and all of it is on my github to reduce clutter for this post. I also will include a screenshot of my GUI and how I have it assigned in JavaFX, perhaps that is where the problem lies. Thank you in advance!

git: https://github.com/jparr721/Blue-Box2/tree/master/src/blueBox/GUI

code for controller class:

```
public class RentGameDialogController extends RentalStoreGUIController implements Initializable{

    @FXML private TextField nameField, rentedOn, dueBack;
    String name;
    Date dateRentedOn, dateDue;
    GregorianCalendar rented, due;
    @FXML ComboBox<GameType> cbGame;
    @FXML ComboBox<PlayerType> cbConsole;
    @FXML Button cancel, addToCart;
    @FXML int counter = 0;
    private Stage currentStage;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        rentedOn = new TextField();
        dueBack = new TextField();

        cbGame = new ComboBox<>();
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleGameComboBox() {
        cbGame.getItems().setAll(GameType.values());
    }
```

code for enum class:

```
public enum GameType {
    THE_WITCHER("The Witcher 3"),
    CALL_OF_DUTY_AW("Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare"),
    CALL_DUTY_BLOP3("Call of Duty: Black Ops 3"),
    CALL_OF_DUTY_IW("Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare"),
    THE_ELDER_SCROLLS("The Elder Scrolls IV: Skyrim");

    private String game;

    GameType(String game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public String GameType() { return game; }

    @Override public String toString() { return game; }

}
```

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/chTYt.png

Comment: If you print `GameType.values();` What do you get?

Comment: Also, I noticed that your `onAction` for the `ComboBox` is set to the `handleGameComboBox()`. I think, in this case, you may want to take the code that is in there now, (the setting of the items) and put that in the `initialize` method, this way it is populated BEFORE `onAction`

Comment: When I print the code with 
'for (GameType g : GameType.values()){
            System.out.println(g);
        }'

It returns the string values I stored in the enum class, however, I am trying to get them to show up and be selectable in my ComboBox. They print fine, so I know that is working, I am just not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, never initialize fields that are injected by `@FXML`. So remove all the code you currently have in your `initialize()` method.

`ObservableList` defines an `addAll(...)` method taking either a varargs or array parameter. So all you need is

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    cbGame.getItems().addAll(GameType.values());
}
```

Comment: Should my combo box be declared with a @FXML tag? Above this method?

Comment: Yes. Don't change the declaration. Just remove its initialization. The initialization will be done by the `@FXML` annotation and the `fx:id ` attribute in the FXML file in the usual way.

Comment: Also, how do I add these values to my comboBox in the GUI?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Isn't that's what I just answered?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I did what you said to do in the initialize method, however, when I assign "cbGame" to the fx:id field in JavaFX I cannot launch the GUI because it says "No injecitble field found."

Comment: @JarredParr That just sounds like an unrelated error (and you haven't posted enough in the question to solve that). I would create a new question for that, with a [MCVE] that replicates the error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answers,in your controller class:

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

  cbGame.getItems().addAll(GameType.values());

}
```

and also make sure that in controller

```
@FXML
    private ComboBox<?> cbGame;
```

is set to:

```
@FXML
    private ComboBox<GameType> cbGame
```